# JqueryMobile ICONS not appearing

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am creating a mobile application for android, and im using jquery mobile with phonegap. But my problem is. I have downloaded the .css and the .js also the images of jquery mobile. and as i run it locally in chrome or safari. the icons is not appearing. i didn't do any custom icons or whatsoever. i just put the .css and images inside my project. and the codes are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />
```

I put the images from jquery mobile into my "images" folder, inside my project.

Thanks

Comment: Look at your NET tab in your debugger, you should see 404 errors for the images in question. Then, look at the paths, where the browser thinks the images are. Is the browser looking in the same place where you put them? If not, move them to where the browser is looking. Good luck!  Feel free to post more information, like the paths where these files are located, if you need more help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Place the Images folder on the path, where the css file has been copied.

for example

```
d:\myproject\jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css

d:\myproject\images
```

Comment: If you're using a custom theme, be sure to places the images folder in the same location as your custom CSS file (in case it is in a different location than your jQuery mobile stuff)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to instead use the CDN (Content Delivery Network) method you can use these three lines inside the head of your HTML:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I ran into this exact problem with icons not showing up in FF or Safari just now and this online solution works for my specific problem.  If you're packaging up for PhoneGap as the OP is, obviously you need the physical files in the proper path(s) as specified above, but this is an alternative if you're writing pre-production code using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a similar site.

These are the latest links as of 13 Jun 2012 and I got them from the [jQuery download site.](http://jquerymobile.com/download/)